# swap elements in array in java refer question in detail

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I have an array of

```java
int [] arr  = {1,2,3,4};
```

Question is:
in above array , given a position = 2;
So arr[2] should be swapped with arr[0]; and rest elements in array should in line like expected output should be : {3, 1 , 2, 4} help me to get the logic

I need an help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: What have you tried and where are your problems?

Comment: i didnt get you mate?

Comment: Unless you provide more detail as to what you want and your attempt at solving this your post will probably be closed.

Comment: Question is:
given array of int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
given a position  = 2;
so arr[2] should be swapped with arr[0];
and rest elements in array should in line like expected output should be :
**{3, 1 , 2, 4}**
help me to get the logic

Comment: Hope you got the question

Comment: This is not swapping.

Answer (score 1):

The task is rotating shift of array elements to the right up to element at `pos` can be simply resolved with decrementing loop:

- store the element at `pos`: `tmp = arr[pos]`;
- shift elements from `pos` downto 0
- put `tmp` to `arr[0]`

```java
public static int[] shiftRightTillPos(int pos, int ... arr) {
    assert pos >= 0 && pos < arr.length;
    
    int tmp = arr[pos];
    for (int i = pos; i > 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[0] = tmp;
    return arr;
}
```

However, this method modifies the input array; a copy may be created with a couple of loops:

```java
public static int[] shiftRightTillPosCopy(int pos, int ... arr) {
    assert pos >= 0 && pos < arr.length;

    int[] res = new int[arr.length];
    res[0] = arr[pos];
    for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {
        res[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = pos + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res[i] = arr[i];
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

or by using [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)):

```java
public static int[] shiftRightTillPosCopy(int pos, int ... arr) {
    assert pos >= 0 && pos < arr.length;

    int[] res = new int[arr.length];
    res[0] = arr[pos];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, res, 1, pos);
    System.arraycopy(arr, pos + 1, res, pos + 1, arr.length - pos - 1);

    return res;
}
```

The last option is to use Stream API - joining several streams using `flatMap`:

```java
public static int[] shiftRightTillPosS(int pos, int ... arr) {
    assert pos >= 0 && pos < arr.length;

    return Stream.of(
        Stream.of(arr[pos]), 
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, pos).map(i -> arr[i - 1]).boxed(),
        IntStream.range(pos + 1, arr.length).map(i -> arr[i]).boxed()
    )
    .flatMap(x -> x)
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an array with a copy of the original except not storing the value at pos.

  1, 2, 3, 4 -> 1, 2, 4
- Assign element at pos to first index in the array
- loop through your original array from indice 1 up to the full length and assign the values of temp (**NOTE** in temp start from one up *indice-1*) to the remaining places.

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class H {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pos = 6;

        int[] arr = {4,1,3,7,6,8,5,2,10,9};
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length-1];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length-1; j++) {
            // skip the entry at pos
            if(j < pos) {
                temp[j] = arr[j];
            
            }else {
                temp[j] = arr[j+1];
            }

        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));

        // first element initialize with element at given position
        arr[0] = arr[pos];
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = temp[i - 1];

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    }
}
```

Outputs

```
[5, 4, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 10,9]
```

Comment: what if for big arrays like: int[] arr = { 4,1,3,7,6,8,5,2,10,9 };
pos : 6;
please do program for it

Comment: i had tried but didnt got desired output mate ;_:

Comment: [5, 4, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 0, 10] got this as output instead of
**[5, 4, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 10,9]**

Comment: hope you got the issue ,

Comment: @TarunKumar mb, I had a misstake in the logic to delete an element. when j < pos then you have to assign arr[j+1] to temp at [j]